# Does anyone have R code for analyzing skin conductance data?

Tags: methodology, physiology, analysis, arousal

Similar question here [Open-source software for analyzing Electrodermal activity](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/open-source-software-for-analyzing-electrodermal-activity)

But with no R code answers provided, and the online EDA explorer appears to be unavailable now.

I am looking for code that takes the raw data and separates the tonic and phasic responses and identifies peaks and their properties.

Thank you!

Comment: The 'similar' question reads like 'the same' question to me, or at least, an overarching/broader one. More specific is generally better though. Maybe we can keep this question, and link the 'R' portion of the other one to this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open-source software for analyzing Electrodermal activity](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/open-source-software-for-analyzing-electrodermal-activity)